Rational parametrization of $a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2=32$
Parametrization of $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ for $a^2-b^2=32$ is $a=p+\frac{8}{p}$, $b=p-\frac{8}{p}$ for $p\in\mathbb{Q-\{0\}}$.
Parametrization of the Pythagorean quadruple is $a=m^2+n^2-p^2-q^2$, $b=2(mq+np)$, $c=2(nq-mp)$, $d=m^2+n^2+p^2+q^2$ for $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$.(ref: Pythagorean_quadruple)
How about the parametrization of the following?

$a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2=32, (a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q})$

Can anyone help? Thank you.

What have you tried?

@Numeral My first attempt was $c=p, d=\frac{16}{p}$ so that $c^2+d^2+32=(p+\frac{16}{p})^2$. In this case, $a$ and $b$ can be like $a=p+\frac{16}{p}, b=0$ or $a=p+\frac{8}{p}, b=4$. However, these are not complete parameterizations.

$(a,b,c,d)=(p^2 - q^2 - 32 r^2 - 1/(4 r^2), p/r, p^2 - q^2 - 32 r^2 + 1/(4 r^2), q/r)$

@DmitryEzhov Thank you. Does your parametrization represent all possible $(a,b,c,d)$s?

@aleph0, no, this is a partial paramatrization

a complete parametrization of rational points is readily available by sterographic projection. More difficult would be trying to select integer points, we don't do that here.
We take an existing solution point  and project around it. I took $(-5,-3,-1,-1).$  Then write $a = -5 + tx, b = -3 + ty, c = -1 + t z, d = -1 + t w,$  plug those into $a^2 + b^2 - c^2 - d^2 = 32,$  finally demand $t$ be nonzero and solve for it.
I'm taking $x,y,z,w$ as integers, no need for them to be anything else.
$$  a = \frac{5x^2 - 5 y^2 + 5 z^2 + 5 w^2 +6xy-2xz-2xw}{x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2}   $$
$$  b = \frac{-3x^2 +3 y^2 + 3 z^2 + 3 w^2 +10xy- 2yz -2yw }{x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2}   $$
$$  c = \frac{-x^2 - y^2 - z^2 +  w^2 +10xz +6yz -2zw }{x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2}   $$
$$  d = \frac{-x^2 - y^2 + z^2 -  w^2 +10xw +6yw -2zw }{x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2}   $$
